# UX design practical

Tags: ux-designer

How to start with UX design practically?

Comment: Create your own website and start applying the lessons learned. It will force you to learn more about UX.

Comment: Hey Anish, welcome to UX.SE. I think this question has potential, but it is too broad in its current form. Could you add some context (your background, your interests in UX, your skillset, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad to answer comprehensively, but there are some books which do that fantastically well.

**Steve Krug's [Don't Make Me Think](https://www.sensible.com/dmmt.html)** is a short and snappy book which explains in basic terms how to perform usability testing.

For a complete guide to the UX process, I would recommend **[About Face](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118766571.html) by Alan Cooper**, **[Lean UX](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021827.do) by Jeff Gothelf**, and **[UX Strategy](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032090.do) by Jaime Levy**.

Each of these books explains a slightly different method of the UX design process, but generally follow the same process of:

1. Review existing solutions.
2. User, customer, and stakeholder interviews.
3. User observation.
4. Create [personas](http://theuxreview.co.uk/personas-the-beginners-guide/) based on previous steps.
5. Identify persona expectations/goals
6. Create [scenarios](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/scenarios.html)
7. Identify design requirements.
8. Define the interaction framework, and validate against personas and scenarios.

   - The users path through the product, information architecture, data elements.
9. Define the visual design framework.
10. Test and validate with users, and repeat if necessary.

Note however that **this is by no means a comprehensive list of steps**. Every methodology varies slightly, and the above is simply an outline.

Answer (score 0):

Well to "start practically" you should create a project for yourself.
Like design a app, or website, or try to redesign a existing product that you think has bad UX.

You can use all the processes that you have learned.

Example for redesign that i like [Craigslist Redesign](https://www.behance.net/gallery/19588499/Craigslist-Redesign-Concept)

Here is [Another one](https://www.behance.net/gallery/32422397/Craiglist-redesign-2016)

Basically internet is full of such projects. Also you could get a good idea of how the process gets implemented.